# Does spring-data-cassandra support @PrePersist?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Just making sure, does Spring Data Cassandra support @PrePersist? I did not find anything about this in its manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time.  Issue is at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-106.